# Prove that $5$ is the only prime $p$ such that $3p + 1$ is a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, square-numbers

Prove that $5$ is the only prime $p$ such that $3p + 1$ is a perfect square.

I started off with assuming that $p$ is odd (since $2$ clearly does not satisfy). This would mean that $3p + 1$ is even. Since if a perfect square is even, it has to be divisible by four, it would mean that $4|3p + 1$.

If $p \equiv 1\pmod 4$, $3p + 1 \equiv 0\space \pmod 4$. All other possible residues of $p \pmod 4$ don't work out. This implies that our proof can be reduced to finding all $m$ such that $3(4m + 1) + 1 = (2n)^2$, or $3m + 1 = n^2$, which looks a lot like our first expression, except, here $m$ does not have to be a prime.

It just remains to be proven that the only $m$ such that $4m + 1$ is a prime and $3m + 1$ is a perfect square is $1$. I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Hint:** If $3p +1 = n^2$, then $ (n-1)(n+1) = 3p$.

What does this tell you about $n$? Why is there only 1 solution?

Comment: Can you explain the whole thing? Please?

Comment: I got it. Since $(n-1)(n+1) = 3p$. One of them must equal $p$ and the other must equal $3$. If $n + 1$ = 3, then $n = 2$, and $n - 1 = 1$, but $1$ is not prime. If $n - 1 = 3$, then $n = 4$ and $n + 1 = p = 5$.

Comment: @euclid Ananay has completed the rest of the steps in his above comment.

Comment: I see... Thanks guys!

Comment: @Ananay Just being pedantic but it would also be necessary to check $(n-1)=1$ and $(n+1)=1$. However, these also yield no results.

Comment: @RiyaVerma I think you overcomplicated it. (I'm not fully certain what you meant by "4/3p+1-4+4. 4/3(p-1). 4/p-1").
We know that one of the terms must be 3. Hence, either $n-1=3$ or $n+1=3$. Just check both cases.

Comment: Ok (actually I just thought that how can we proceed after 4/3p+1 ,as the asker did, another method may be) but it's alright. it seemed messy to me so I deleted it :)